# Transformer ratio of a transformer that connects a generator to a MV grid?

Tags: voltage, power, transformer, generator, power-grid

Inside my one-line diagram in which I am studying some properties of the medium voltage grid, I want to connect a generator to the MV busbar to study the hosting capacity. Therefore there is not a fixed rated power of the generator because to study the hosting capacity I have to vary it (increasing the rated power step by step). Since generators are usually connected to the grid through a transformer, how should I modify the transformer ratio when the rated power changes? Looking at the attached figure, for sure it would be kt=22kV/Vn_gen, where Vn_gen is the nominal voltage of the generator, but how does it vary by varying the rated power of the generator? Last doubt: why usually generators are connected to the grid through a transformer? Supposing that the nominal voltage of the generator is almost the grid one, should a transformer be inserted? [image]

Comment: As the generator power increases, its voltage usually remains approximately constant, it supplies more current. (Thus I^2*R losses mean a SLIGHT voltage increase but nothing that requires changing the transformer tap)

Comment: @user_1818839 thank you! I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer your questions below.

> how should I modify the transformer ratio when the rated power changes?

- You should not change the voltage ratio due to the rated power of the generator.

> Looking at the attached figure, for sure it would be kt=22kV/Vn_gen, where Vn_gen is the nominal voltage of the generator, but how does it vary by varying the rated power of the generator?

- The power of the generator does not depend on the voltage of the generator. The typical scenario is that voltages are fixed for electrical equipment (due to safety and cost-effectiveness issues) and as the power increases, the current increases in the same proportion.

> Last doubt: why usually generators are connected to the grid through a transformer?

- Usually, generator voltage levels are lower than grid voltage levels. Another reason is the need for galvanic isolation (which brings more safety to the operation of the generator).

> Supposing that the nominal voltage of the generator is almost the grid one, should a transformer be inserted?

- As far as I know, it is not common to find generators above 15kV.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear now!

Comment: may I ask you just last thing? What is the rated power of a transformer to connect a generator? Is it 50-80% the rated power of the generator?

Comment: Hi! It will depend on the power factor, once the transformer should be sized for the apparent power.